# how to show 7 images jquery carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to write code same like this [demo](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/demo.php), It tried this one by following changes but problem is immediate image not coming after completion loop it coming

```
#jcl-demo .carousel {
    width: 98% !important;
    position: relative;
    visibility: hidden;
    left: -5000px;
    margin:auto;
}


#jcl-demo .carousel>ul>li>img {
    width:100%;
    height: 335px;
    vertical-align:middle;       
}
```

Comment: $("element").jCarouselLite({
    visible: 7});

Comment: not working can you explain me little bit  more I tried code is    $(function() {
            
        }
           $(".moreItems .carousel ul li").jCarouselLite({ visible: 7});
        });

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".moreItems .carousel").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".moreItems .next",
        btnPrev: ".moreItems .prev",
        visible: 7
   })
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xwL8nfry/

Comment: yes tried this once also not display any thing only black screen is visible

Comment: IT IS ALSO NOT WORKING $(function() { 
    $(".moreItems").jCarouselLite({ 
        visible: 7
     }); 
});

Comment: yes it working but problem is it is not screen width I mean looking is not working correct way

Comment: my screen with 1600*900, in this screen dispaying 9 images , not working loopback , scrooling left to right 8th and 9th is position show is emtpy